# Are all cycles in a graph always maximal/minimal cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

The following definition of **maximal cycle** is given in the paper ["On a cyclic connectivity property of directed graphs"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X07001458),

> We call a cycle $C$ of a digraph $D$ *maximal* if there is no cycle $C_1$ in $D$ that is longer and contains all vertices of $C$.

I wonder if this is usual in graph theory? Since in my understanding, some subgraph is maximal if it cannot be extended while still maintaining the original edges and vertices. Thus cycles are automatically maximal and minimal (or is this claim incorrect? I cannot find any references).

I follow the convention in the graph theory book by Douglas West. An $n$-cycle has $n$ edges and $n$ vertices.

(Along the line I found out that some other authors refer to cycle as "simple cycle", and closed trail as "cycle".)

Comment: Maximality is only with respect to the vertex set, *not* the edge set. So in $K_4$, no 3-cycle is maximal, because it's vertex set is contained in the vertex set of a 4-cycle.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez, this is strange to me. I'm really new to graph theory. Could you pls provide some reference that specifically excludes edge set in mentioning maximality? Many thanks!

Comment: The definition you give in the post says "and contains all the vertices of $C$", so the link you give is one such source. As you mentioned in your post, it's impossible for one cycle to be a subgraph of a different cycle, so there'd be no point in discussing minimality with respect to edges.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a reflection

One should remember that notions like *maximal* (*minimal*, etc.) have their set-theoretic definitions. Formally, we define some predicate $M(x)$. This predicate reflects the basic properties of an object $a$ that seems to us maximal in some sense, i.e. we have $M(a)$. One may consider a new object $b$ such that $M(b)$. In its turn, $b$ may not "seem" to be maximal since $M(x)$ is a kind of simplification and may not reflect the property per se. One may consider $b$ if it helps him prove some assertion. Then, instead of writing the sentence $M(b)$, he can say that $b$ is maximal. Thus, there is no restriction on when to use a notion like *maximal* other than $M(x)$ must be satisfied.

Now, formally, given a preorder $\leq$ (reflexive and transitive relation over a set $S$), the property $M(x)$ of being maximal is defined as:
\begin{align}
M(x)\iff\lnot\exists y:x\neq y\land x\leq y
\end{align}
In the given case, the underlying set $S$ is the set of all cycles of $D$, and $\leq$ is just the following relation:
\begin{align}
C_1\leq C_2\iff V(C_1)\subseteq V(C_2)
\end{align}
Though, one may define another preorder $\leq$ over subgraphs and consider maximal elements of $\leq$.

Comment: Thanks for going deep into preorder! I have no objection regarding the author's terminology, especially the definition is provided in the paper. I am wondering generally in graph theory if the maximality requires concerning both the vertex set and edge set?

Comment: tried to edit to make the reflections a bit more clear